# Flask DateTime won't set with default datetime.utcnow

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to SQLAlchemy and have been unable to set the DateTime for created.  I have tried using the "default" option found in many examples.  I have also tried setting it manually (I have it commented out).  Neither have worked so far.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
models.py

import datetime
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

db = SQLAlchemy()

class User(db.Model):

  __tablename__    = 'users'
  uid              = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  firstname        = db.Column(db.String(40))
  lastname         = db.Column(db.String(40))
  email            = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
  created          = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
  confirmed        = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
  pwdhash          = db.Column(db.String(100))

  def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, email, password):
    self.firstname = firstname.title()
    self.lastname  = lastname.title()
    self.email     = email.lower()
    self.set_password(password)
    #self.created   = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    self.confirmed = None

  def set_password(self, password):
    self.pwdhash   = generate_password_hash(password)

  def check_password(self, password):
    return check_password_hash(self.pwdhash, password)

routes.py

from tasks import app
from datetime import datetime
from flask import render_template, request, flash, session, url_for, redirect
from forms import ContactForm, SignupForm, SigninForm
from flask.ext.mail import Message, Mail
from models import db, User, Tags, Tasks

@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
  form = SignupForm()

  if 'email' in session:
    return redirect(url_for('profile')) 

  if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.validate() == False:
      return render_template('signup.html', form=form)
    else:
      newuser = User(form.firstname.data, form.lastname.data, form.email.data, form.password.data)
      db.session.add(newuser)
      db.session.commit()

      session['email'] = newuser.email
      return redirect(url_for('profile'))

  elif request.method == 'GET':
    return render_template('signup.html', form=form)
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem with your `default` is that you're calling `datetime.utcnow` immediately there, and the value returned (at the time of class definition) is always used as default.  You need to pass the callable itself like following:

```py
# Note the lack of parenthesis after datetime.utcnow
created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
```

This way SQLAlchemy will call `datetime.utcnow` itself upon row insert.